# What kind of wall texture is this?

Tags: drywall

Can someone help me identify this texture and how it was created. This is not a ceiling it is on my walls.[image]

Comment: How old is the finish or the house?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some sort of orange peel

[image]

Comment: I would agree with orange peal. maybe texture sprayed a bit wet , or possible several coats of paint give the current look.